# Doctrine Extensions Tranlatable with Slugable

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, slug

When i translate an entity, everything is fine but slug.

My entity:

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\Translatable
 * @var string
 */
private $slug;
```

My Orm.yml

```
slug:
  type: string
  length: 1000
  nullable: false
  gedmo:
    translatable: {}
    slug:
      separator: -
      fields:
        - title
```

My ext_translations table:

[image: ext_translations table]

Title and content successfully translated to given language. Slug is generating over title in posts table. I could not translate slug.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change from Doctrine Extensions to [DoctrineBehaviors](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors), because the development of the doctrine extensions has stopped. Also what you want is easily possible with doctrine behaviour:

#### Your `Entity` class:

```
class Entity {

   use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

}
```

#### Your `EntityTranslation` class:

```
class EntityTranslation {

    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation;
    use ORMBehaviors\Sluggable\Sluggable;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $title;

    public function getSluggableFields()
    {
        return [ 'title' ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but i'm searching for a solution for dextensions problem. I will note your answer for next projects.

Comment: I strongly suggest you change to the newer bundle. But if you are unable to or decide not to maybe [this link](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md#using-translationlistener-to-translate-our-slug) can help you

Comment: Yeah i'm not able to chane the bundle right now. I'v checked that link  23213 times i think. I'm missing something but what...